# Python- web scraping, for loop in function doens't work

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I'm studying python-web **scraping**, and I want to make a function automatically scrape the rates of webtoons.
I thought it was quite simple job, but the for loop in 'score' function doesn't work.
But the last three for loop I commented out works properly.
How can I fix the 'score'function???

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://comic.naver.com/webtoon/list?titleId=183559&weekday=mon"
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
# scraping rates
cartoons_1 = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"rating_type"})
total_rates = 0
def score(cartoons):
    global total_rates
    for cartoon in cartoons:
        rate = cartoon.find("strong").get_text()
        print(rate)
        total_rates = total_rates + float(rate)
        return total_rates
total_rates = score(cartoons_1)
print("average rates: ", total_rates/len(cartoons_1))
# for cartoon in cartoons_1:
#     rate = cartoon.find("strong").get_text()
#     print(rate)
```

Expected result was
9.91
9.83
9.89
9.89
9.78
9.89
9.90
9.81
9.90
9.85
average rates:  9.865

---

But the result was
9.91
average rates:  0.991

---

For loop in the function doens't work.

Comment: FYI it’s scraping (and scrape, scraper,  scraped) not scrapping. Scrapping means throwing away like rubbish, or fighting.

Comment: Haha thank you! python study + english study

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `cartoons_1` but not `cartoons`. I think what you are trying to do is this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://comic.naver.com/webtoon/list?titleId=183559&weekday=mon"
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
# scrapping rates
cartoons_1 = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"rating_type"})
total_rates = 0
def score(cartoons):
    global total_rates
    for cartoon in cartoons:
        rate = cartoon.find("strong").get_text()
        print(cartoon)
        print(rate)
        total_rates = total_rates + float(rate)
        return total_rates
total_rates = score(cartoons_1)
print("total rates: ", total_rates)
print("average rates: ", total_rates/len(cartoons_1))
for cartoon in cartoons_1:
    rate = cartoon.find("strong").get_text()
    print(rate)
```

Comment: I understand what you say, I fixed the for loops below, but I can't find any difference inside the function...

Comment: Do you mean why isn't the loop in the function printing all the values? If so it's because the `return total_rates` makes it exit the function as soon as it hits that line.

Comment: I added comment to say thank you an hour ago, but it disappered.. Anyway, thank you so much. It worked!! :D